# Swipe Fragments Android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to make a app where its basically a book. Inside this app it has books, which has chapters, which has verses. I'm trying to decide which is the best way to implement this. I'm using fragments and swipe views,and when i swipe to the to the next page the it will change chapters. My question is since this app is going to have about a hundred books, more chapters, and many more versus, I don't think making new Fragments for each chapter would be good for the app performance. Is there a certain method or layout which suits my app best?

Comment: "I don't think making new Fragments for each chapter would be good for the app performance" -- if you use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with `ViewPager`, you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, i'm looking into FragmentPagerAdapter and ViewPager now and this is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want curl animation like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP_AlvJqSLQ

to achive this animation use  overridePendingTransition:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));  
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in,R.anim.push_up_out);
```

push_left_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

  <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>  
  <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />  

</set>
```

push_up_out.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

  <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>  

</set>
```

If you want tutorial or sample, Please follow below link:

1. http://www.41post.com/3368/programming/android-changing-the-animation-between-activities
2. https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl
3. https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView
4. https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl